# what kinds of statistical methods fit to the following problem?

Tags: markov-process

I am trying to solve the following problem with a xlm file, but I have doubts about the method.

There is a person who needs to reach 11 different planets in sequence. In order to do that he uses a Teleport potion. The problem of this potion is that can fail and bring you back to the previous planet. In particular, we talk about:

- success = when he reaches the next planet
- fail = he takes a step back (previous planet)
- pass = he stays there (no changes)

The question is: How can I find the number of times he needs to use the potion to reach the last planet? E.g.,

- From planet 1 to 2 - 75% of success - 00% of fail - 25% of pass
- From planet 2 to 3 - 40% of success - 00% of fail - 60% of pass
- From planet 3 to 4 - 30% of success - 40% of fail - 30% of pass
- From planet 4 to 5 - 20% of success - 50% of fail - 30% of pass
- From planet 5 to 6 - 20% of success - 50% of fail - 30% of pass
- From planet 6 to 7 - 20% of success - 40% of fail - 40% of pass
- From planet 7 to 8 - 20% of success - 40% of fail - 40% of pass
- From planet 8 to 9 - 20% of success - 40% of fail - 40% of pass
- From planet 9 to 10 - 20% of success - 40% of fail - 40% of pass
- From planet 10 to 11 - 20% of success - 40% of fail - 40% of pass

Comment: Don't you really want the probability distribution for the number of times he uses the potion.  For example he can use it a minimum of 3 times if he has three consecutive successes.  The probability for that is 0.6x0.6x0.3=0.108. for 4 times it gets more complicated as there are several ways for this to happen. You can get there with one pass and three successes where the pass can occur on planets 1, 2 or 3. For 5 the number of ways can involve a failure or two passes and it gets more complicated.

Comment: This is a combinatorial problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael and, thanks for editing Mark. So more steps, more complicated, therefore, as example, if I would like to know the minimum amount of times I need to use the potion to reach  10 planets, and every step has different %age of success. Shall I multiply all %ages of success?

Comment: The combinatorics are complicated for just 4 planets. For 10 planets to do it in 9 steps would take all successes and yes that probability would be to multiply the probability of success at each planet.  To get the distribution would require knowing probability of failing and passing at each planet other than planet 1.

Comment: Thanks Michael, so to calculate how many tries he needs to reach the last planet I should calculate the chance for each and then sum those.

Comment: That will take a lot of calculation.  After all, the median number of tries is $2811$ and there's still a one percent chance it will take more than $18,537$ tries.  The theory of [discrete Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) gives you a much more efficient method.  It requires analyzing the transition matrix you have defined into its eigenvectors and eigenvalues and using that to compute very high powers of the matrix quickly.